# Fix crispy/jagged rendering of text after CSS3 rotation

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

I'm sure that you're noticed annoying look of text after CSS3 rotation. Text looks so crispy, jagged, unaligned...

I've found some answers which include `-webkit-font-smoothing` but that doesn't have effect at all.

After that, I've found my own solution: simply apply some `filter` property! Yes that works! It works with any filter (opacity, grayscale, blur)!

So if we rotate some text, and apply (for Chrome)

```
-webkit-filter: blur(0px);
```

and (for FF)

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

result is much better. Text is aligned nice, there is no crispy and jagged effect. But... now text is blured a bit. Not because filter `blur`, same result is with any other filter. And again, `-webkit-font-smoothing` doesn't have effect.

**[Here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NKgHW/)** , you can see a difference between those two paragraphs.
(You can even better see a difference if you apply [`color: red;` on `p`](http://jsfiddle.net/NKgHW/10/).)

---

Now, my question is - is there some better way to fix this rendering problem after text rotation, using some other properties? Or at least how to fix this blur effect after using filters?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0); for the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn’t much that can be done about this.

Computer fonts are developed to be displayed in a grid of horizontal and vertically aligned quadratic pixels – and rotating characters by anything else than a multiple of 90° (or maybe 45°) can hardly produce satisfying results (at least not at the small sizes fonts are displayed on a normal website¹) because there’s still only quadratic pixels available to render them, and therefor a lot of rounding and interpolating has to occur, so that you end up with multiple pixels now having to somehow display parts of what was meant to be only one little “dot” before – and even sub-pixel rendering can’t fix that (sometimes it even adds to the perceived “blurriness” of rotated text).

---

¹ Try changing the font-size in your fiddle to say 5em – and you will notice that the rotated text looks very good. For small text sizes that is just not possible, at least not with todays screen’s pixel densities (might look a little better on a retina display than on a normal TFT).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention that rotating characters by anything else than a multiple of 90° can hardly produce satisfying results. So, there is no better way to "fix" this (for small/normal font sizes) than using filters, as in my fiddle? Blurred result is not perfect, but is much better than that crispy look. (IMHO)